# Undefined reference to a function in Vscode but I am sure that I have that function

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

So I have three files in the same folder open in Vscode: main.c employee.c and employee.h

The employee.h is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef struct payment{
    char* date;         //  MM/DD/YY as text
    float amount;
    struct payment* next;
}PAYMENT;

typedef struct employee{
    int id;
    char* name;
    PAYMENT* payments;
    struct employee* next;
}EMPLOYEE;

void printEmployee(EMPLOYEE e);
void printEmployees();
void addEmployee(int e_id,char* e_name);
int addPayment(int e_id, char* p_date, float p_amount);
int deleteEmployee(int e_id, char* e_name);
```

And the employee.c is

```
#include "employee.h"




EMPLOYEE* list_of_employees=NULL;
void printEmployee(EMPLOYEE e){
    printf("Name: %s, ", e.name);
    printf("ID: %d\n", e.id);
    PAYMENT* temp=e.payments;
    if (temp) {
        printf("------------------------\n"); 
        printf("Date       |Amount\n");
        printf("----       |-----\n"); 
        while (temp) {
            printf("%s |%.6f\n", temp->date, temp->amount); 
            temp=temp->next;
        }
    } else {
        printf("No Payments..\n");
    }
    
}


void addEmployee(int e_id, char* e_name){
    // Your code here
    EMPLOYEE* new_employee = (EMPLOYEE*)malloc(sizeof(EMPLOYEE));
    new_employee->id=e_id;
    new_employee->name=e_name;
    new_employee->payments=NULL;
    new_employee->next=list_of_employees;
    list_of_employees=new_employee;
}

void printEmployees(){
    // Your code here
    EMPLOYEE* temp =list_of_employees;
    if(temp==NULL){
        printf("This list is empty..\n");
    }
    while(temp!=NULL){
        printEmployee(*temp);
        printf("==========================\n"); 
        temp=temp->next;
    }

}

int addPayment(int e_id, char* p_date, float p_amount){
    // Your code here
    EMPLOYEE*temp=list_of_employees;
    while(temp!=NULL){
        if(temp->id==e_id){
            PAYMENT*new_payment=(PAYMENT*)malloc(sizeof(PAYMENT));
            new_payment->date=p_date;
            new_payment->amount=p_amount;
            new_payment->next=temp->payments;
            temp->payments=new_payment;
            return 1;
        }
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    return 0;

}

int deleteEmployee(int e_id, char* e_name){
    // Your code here
    EMPLOYEE*temp=list_of_employees;
    EMPLOYEE*prev=NULL;
    while(temp!=NULL){
        if(temp->id==e_id){
            if(prev==NULL){
                list_of_employees=temp->next;
            }
            else{
                prev->next=temp->next;
            }
            free(temp);
            return 1;
        }
        prev=temp;
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    return 0;

}
```

In the Main.c: I just wanted to try the printEmployee function first

```
 #include "employee.h" 
 #include "employee.c" 
int main(){
    EMPLOYEE e;
    e.name="james";
    e.id=123456;
    e.next=NULL;
    e.payments=NULL;
    printEmployee(e);
}
```

I have Vscode set to run in terminal and after I hit run, it keeps saying undefined reference to "printEmployee" and collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
I wonder why it happens

Comment: Also in terminal I have tried gcc main.c employee.c and employee.h

Comment: where is employee header in main file ?

Comment: Yeah in the main file, I also have #include "employee.h" and  #include "employee.c"

Comment: How is this being compiled, is the second filed also being compiled or its just main.c, if you are just using the play button on IDE that might not work, edit the preferences of your IDE, if you are using GCC pass the second file as argument as well.

Comment: undefined reference basically means, you are telling your compiler, that a function exists somewhere, and its definition is in the header file, and it is the job of the linker to link them, if you are not passing the object file that contains the print function you were getting reference error with, that's going to be an issue.

Comment: How do I use GCC to pass the second file as argument? Does that mean I should type gcc main.c employee.c in the Vscode terminal?

Comment: use a build tool, trying to get a 50 `.c` files program to compile using a convoluted task is crazy and it costs you a lot of compile time because every thing is always compiled